# Line Icon whatsapp icon CSS style

Tags: html, css

What I want is to make it look like a Whatsapp icon that appears in Android phones i.e without the square black background. How to achieve this?

I have a line icon of whatsapp use  its give me whatsapp icon with white background now i want to change its background color to black using CSS.

If i changed background color its shape change to square format.

Comment: Hi Ravi, welcome to SO. Please provide more context on the problem. This will help you with asking questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi Eisenheim I have a line icon of whatsapp  use <i class="icon-whatsapp">   its give me whatsapp icon with white background now i want to change his background color black using css.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation. Don't use comments in this case.

Comment: Which icons library are you using?

Comment: Mosh Feu  I am using varient-icons.min.css

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you are trying to do, Please put in more detail

But you can try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Change Image on Hover in CSS</title>
<style>
    .card {
        width: 130px;
        height: 195px;
        background: url("black image link") no-repeat;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .card:hover {
        background: url("white image link") no-repeat;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="card"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: He is actually trying to make a whatsapp icon and want to change the background color of icon

Comment: That's what I did, It changes the picture